# Treat visual representation of integer as hexadecimal to place in guid

Tags: c#, .net

We have a legacy requirement to store what are now newly migrated `int` ID values into a `guid` type for use on ID-agnostic data types (basically old code that took advantage of the "globally unique" part of `guid` in order to contain all possible IDs in one column/field).

Due to this requirement, there was a follow-on requirement to embed the integer ID of entites into `guid` in a ***human-readable manner***. This is important and is currently what is stopping me from working against the byte values directly.

Currently, I have the following:

```
    public static byte[] IntAsHexBytes(int value)
    {
        return BitConverter.GetBytes(Convert.ToInt64(value.ToString(), 16));
    }

    public static Guid EmbedInteger(int id)
    {
        var ib = IntAsHexBytes(id);

        return new Guid(new byte[]
            {
                0,0,0,0,0,0,1,64,ib[7],ib[6],ib[5],ib[4],ib[3],ib[2],ib[1],ib[0]
            });
    }
```

It treats the visual representation of the `int` as a hex value (`value.ToString()`), converts *that* to a `long` (`Convert.ToInt64(value.ToString(), 16)`) and the grabs the bytes from the `long` into a flattened `byte[]` for creating a `guid` in a particular structure.

So given an `int` of 42, when you treat 42 as a hex and convert *that* to an `long` you get 66, and on to the bytes of 66 gives, placing into a `guid` gives:

```
"00000000-0000-4001-0000-000000000042"
```

And an `int` of `379932126` gives:

```
"00000000-0000-4001-0000-000379932126"
```

So the end result is to place the integer into the `guid` in the last 12 digits so it visually looks like the integer 42 (even though the underlying integer value was 66).

This is roughly 30%-40% faster than constructing a string using concatenation in order to feed into the `new Guid(string)` constructor, but I feel I'm missing the solution that avoids having to do anything with strings in the first place.

The actual timings involved are quite small so as a performance improvement it probably won't justify the effort.

This is *purely* for the sake of my own curiosity to see if there are faster ways of tackling this problem. I posted here as I'm a long-standing SO user, but I'm torn as to whether this is a code-review-ish question, though I'm not asking for anything against my code directly, it just demonstrates what I want as output.

The integer range being supplied is 0 to `int.MaxValue`.

**Update:** For completeness, this is what we currently have and what I'm testing against:

```
string s = string.Format("00000000-0000-4001-0000-{0:D12}", id);
return new Guid(s);
```

My other code above is faster than this by around 30%.

Comment: I must be missing something important. If you treat the decimal representation of an integer as if it were hex, when you parse it back via the Convert.ToInt32(value, base) you surely can get an overflow? I just don't understand I guess... But IntAsHexBytes(int.MaxValue) will certainly throw an exception.

Comment: @MatthewWatson The return value was extracted as an integer by converting the guid to a string, sub-stringing that to get the last section and supplying that to `int.Parse`. We don't do it this way any more because someone found a way to work against the bytes directly in order to extract the integer, but no one has found the reverse alternative to my code above.

Comment: Well if you're serious about the input range being 0 to int.MaxValue, your code won't work. But when you say you supplied the last section (presumably the last 8 hex digits if in string form?) to Int.Parse(), you parsed it as hex, yes?

Comment: @MatthewWatson Amended, good spot - and when I thought about it on paper I came to the same conclusion, the resulting integer value of the hex overflows some time before `int.MaxValue`. My timing code was only going to 1000000.

Comment: While you're at it, could you give an example where the integer is greater than 99? I'm thinking that an input of 123456 should put the following at the end of the GUID string: -000000123456. Is that correct?

Comment: @MatthewWatson You are correct, it does, that is where I want it. I've added another example. I can also post the code used to extract the 'int' ID from the `guid` if need-be, but it is a little verbose.

Comment: It's OK, I think I have something - just testing. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here's another version which completely avoids strings. Hopefully this might be better. :)

```
public static Guid EmbedInteger(int id)
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[8];
    int i = 0;

    while (id > 0)
    {
        int remainder = id%100;
        bytes[i++] = (byte)(16*(remainder/10) + remainder%10);
        id /= 100;
    }

    return new Guid(0, 0, 0x4001, bytes[7], bytes[6], bytes[5], bytes[4], bytes[3], bytes[2], bytes[1], bytes[0]);
}
```

**Adam Houldsworth: Update:** This code can also be unrolled:

```
int remainder = id % 100;
bytes[0] = (byte)(16 * (remainder / 10) + remainder % 10);
id /= 100;
if (id == 0) return;
remainder = id % 100;
bytes[1] = (byte)(16 * (remainder / 10) + remainder % 10);
id /= 100;
if (id == 0) return;
remainder = id % 100;
bytes[2] = (byte)(16 * (remainder / 10) + remainder % 10);
id /= 100;
if (id == 0) return;
remainder = id % 100;
bytes[3] = (byte)(16 * (remainder / 10) + remainder % 10);
id /= 100;
if (id == 0) return;
remainder = id % 100;
bytes[4] = (byte)(16 * (remainder / 10) + remainder % 10);
```

Comment: +1 I had to make the edits you made, I did them offline before I got your edit, but this cuts the time a lot. Well, "a lot" is subjective. The first solution took 550ms, my solution took 300ms, yours takes 100ms, but you found the magic maths that makes 42 -> 66 :D

Comment: Just as an aside, you only need a `byte[5]` to take whatever `int.MaxValue` is as a hex-int.

Comment: I also don't need to post the code that extracts the ID, because it has calculations that look a lot like this, just going in reverse. This is exactly what I was after. I've +1'd your other answer even though it wasn't what I was after lol

Comment: If you're calling this in a loop, you could get super-fussy about optimising it and create the byte[] array outside the loop and pass it into the EmbedInteger() method to avoid repeated array creation. ;)

Comment: I got super-fussy and used bytes in-line as opposed to an array :-)

Answer (score 1):

I *think* this will do what you want. Not sure if it is any more efficient than your code, but it is a little shorter at least. :)

```
public static Guid EmbedInteger(int id)
{
    string guid = string.Format("00000000-0000-4001-0000-{0,12:D12}", id);
    return new Guid(guid);
}
```

It works by using the numeric format 12:D12 which causes the input number to be formatted as a decimal in a field width of 12 with leading zeroes.

Comment: That is actually what we currently have, it is slightly less efficient than what I posted above. Though I'm not sure if it is the format call or the guid string constructor that is responsible for it.

Comment: I think the OP actually wants to avoid the constructor that takes a string as parameter for performances reason.